# Position an element on an empty container responsively

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, position

I got the following problem. I want to display a map on a site. The map is a background image.

This Code makes the image perfectly responsible.

```
section#map {
    max-width: 960px;   
}

div#map-image {
    background: url(Map.jpg) top left no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    padding-top: 41.875%; /* 402px/960px = 0.41875 height/width of map */
}
```

So far so good!

But now I want to have some sort of location pin on that map, that behaves also responsive. Since I want to animate it I didn't include in the map graphics, so that is of the table.

Is that possible to do?

Using `position:relative;` doesn't work because the parent element do not have a width/height specified. Margin/Padding didn't work either.

style for the location pin:

```
span#location 
{
    background-color: red;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    border-radius: 6px;

    /*position: relative;
    top: 86.9%;
    left: 52.26%;*/
}
```

html looks like this:

```
<section id="map">  
    <span id="location"></span>
    <div id="map-image"></div>
</section>
```

Any ideas how to pull this off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `position: relative`to `#map`  the width of the map seems to be 100% of its parent. `position:relative` for the pin should then work.

Unless you set the map to position:relative, any relative or absolute positioned elements within that `<section id="map">` will take its relative position from the `<body>`

Comment: Thanks, but I think you got a typo there: It works when I set `#map` to `position:relative;` and `#location` to `position:absolute`

Answer (score 1):

Can't test it because I don't have the map-image, but this seems working:

```
position: absolute;
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6pUbK/)